# Strimzi Apache Kafka operator doesn't respect auto.create.topics.enable

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I created a kafka cluster with strimzi operator (version 0.28.0) with the following settings:

```
spec:
  kafka:
    config:
      log.retention.hours: 5
      auto.create.topics.enable: false
      default.replication.factor: 3
      min.insync.replicas: 2
```

Assuming that no topic will be created automatically, I added two topic definitions:

1. `_schemas` for schema registry
2. `__consumer_offsets` for consumer groups

However after launching the cluster, I see two auto created topics as well:

1. `__strimzi_store_topic` which is represented by `strimzi-store-topic---effb8e3e057afce1ecf67c3f5d8e4e3ff177fc55` Kubernetes resource.
2. `strimzi-topic-operator-kstreams-topic-store-changelog` which is represented by `strimzi-topic-operator-kstreams-topic-store-changelog---b75e702040b99be8a9263134de3507fc0cc4017b` Kubernetes resource.

The hash appended to resource names shows that they have been created outside (without using `kind: KafkaTopic` CRD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did an Internet search for `auto.create.topics.enable` and the first result which explained what this configuration does is [here](https://riferrei.com/why-the-property-auto-create-topics-enable-is-disabled-in-confluent-cloud/). It says:

> ... there is a property named auto.create.topics.enable that allows topics to be automatically created when producers try to write data into it. That means that if a producer tries to write an record to a topic named customers and that topic doesn’t exist yet — it will be automatically created to allow the writing. Instead of returning an error to the client.

The topics you see created by Strimzi are not created as an automatic result of a producer trying to write to them, but because Strimzi needs them for its own internal state management purposes, so it has created them explicitly.

What you should see is if you try to produce to a topic called `foo`, it will fail.

If you instead set `auto.create.topics.enable: true` and tried the same thing with a producer, it will not fail, and `foo` will be automatically created on the fly by Kafka.